# Cloud foundry scale

Tags: docker, cloud, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

In cloud foundry there is option to scale app, my question is what happen when I scale app?
if the app running in garden/docker does it create new container per the scale the I requested or the application running in the same container ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the elastic runtime, the default settings for a container are set. These include the memory, ephemeral disk etc. As part of the `cf push` (either thru manifest file, or at command line) you can override those parameters. With push of an app, the LRP settings and the archives are uploaded to the cloud foundry blob store.

Scaling can be vertical (increase memory, and/or disk) or horizontal (additional instances). Also scaling can be manual or auto-scaling (more on it later).

My understanding is that, in both cases of manual scaling, cloud foundry will create a new container instance with the new values (mem, disk). CF will pull archives for the LRP from the blob store, and push it to the container and invoke the LRP. Once it up, the old instance is shutdown and reclaimed.

Autoscaling is for horizontal scaling only. First you need to create a service instance of the auto-scaler. You bind the auto-scaler with your LRP and provide details on how the auto-scaler should work - cpu %, min, max, number of instances etc. Once that has been set, CF will auto scale the app/LRPs based on the provided details.

I am no expert in cloud foundry. So, I request the experts to please correct me. It is always good to learn.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a good answer. Horizontal scaling with "cf scale -i INSTANCES" creates a new container for each instance if scaling up or deletes containers if scaling down. Vertical scaling of resources with "cf scale -m MEMORY -k DISK" creates a new container with the requested resources and re-deploys the app bits from the blobstore. The only correction is that an app is not restaged in either case - the staged app bits are just retrieved from the blobstore and deployed to the container.

Comment: so autoscaling instances vertically feature is not enabled in cloud foundary?